# SQL Server how to select from a table where StartDate and EndDate is within 6 months ago

Tags: sql-server

So I have a table with some columns as listed in the below select statement.

```
SELECT [AccountName], 
       [AccountNumber], 
       [Tenor], 
       [Currency], 
       [TotalCredit], 
       [TotalDebit], 
       [CreditCount], 
       [DebitCount], 
       [AccountBalance], 
       [StatementStartDate], 
       [StatementEndDate] 
  FROM [TAF.EligibilityService].[dbo].[AccountStatements]
```

[image]

I will like to select records that exist between 6 months ago and today using the **StatementStartDate** and **StatementEndDate**.

For example, if the start date is 1 year ago, as long as the end date is still within 6 months ago, the record should be returned.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This wraps a known value, `GETDATE()`, in a function, which only requires a single calculation, instead of wrapping the column in a function, which would require evaluation the calculation *for every row*.

```
SELECT [AccountName], 
       [AccountNumber], 
       [Tenor], 
       [Currency], 
       [TotalCredit], 
       [TotalDebit], 
       [CreditCount], 
       [DebitCount], 
       [AccountBalance], 
       [StatementStartDate], 
       [StatementEndDate]   
  FROM [TAF.EligibilityService].[dbo].[AccountStatements]
 WHERE StatementStartDate >= dateadd(month, -6, getdate())
    OR StatementEndDate>= dateadd(month, -6, getdate());
```

Based on indexes, data size and performance needs, splitting the `OR` into two `UNION` statements may be the next step.  Something like:

```
SELECT [AccountName], 
       [AccountNumber], 
       [Tenor], 
       [Currency], 
       [TotalCredit], 
       [TotalDebit], 
       [CreditCount], 
       [DebitCount], 
       [AccountBalance], 
       [StatementStartDate], 
       [StatementEndDate]   
  FROM [TAF.EligibilityService].[dbo].[AccountStatements]
 WHERE StatementStartDate >= dateadd(month, -6, getdate())
UNION ALL
SELECT [AccountName], 
       [AccountNumber], 
       [Tenor], 
       [Currency], 
       [TotalCredit], 
       [TotalDebit], 
       [CreditCount], 
       [DebitCount], 
       [AccountBalance], 
       [StatementStartDate], 
       [StatementEndDate]   
  FROM [TAF.EligibilityService].[dbo].[AccountStatements]
 WHERE StatementEndDate>= dateadd(month, -6, getdate());
```

Comment: Thank you all. This works well.